# jQuery background-position left to right, right to left

Tags: jquery

I want to animate an element's background-position from left to right, to right to left (or vice versa) and keep repeating it. I accomplished this, but in a wrong way.

1. Code is messy
2. Element's background-position does stop animating after a while.

   ```
   window.setInterval(function(){
       if($(element).css("background-position") == posRight + "px 50%"){
           move("left");
       } else if($(element).css("background-position") == posLeft + "px 50%"){
           move("right");
       }
   }, 500);
   ```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is the setInterval, but I don't know what I can use instead. If I don't use the interval, the if-statement doesn't get checked (or just once). If I decrease the interval time, it simply won't work because the if-statement checks if the position is at X, but the position starts at X, so it doesn't do anything.

**Where am I talking about?**
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8eS3a/1/

**What do I want?**
A workaround for the setInterval.

*You may change the gradient to a background image to see what's going on. I used a gradient, because sometimes images get deleted.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback built into `animate()`, like so:

```
function changePos(element, posLeft, posRight, duration) {
    var state = $(element).data('state'),
        pos   = state ? posRight : posLeft;

    $(element).animate({backgroundPosition: pos}, duration, function () {
        changePos(element, posLeft, posRight, duration);
    }).data('state', !state);
}

changePos("#elem1", 0, 40, 300);
changePos("#elem2", 0, 40, 600);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eS3a/2/)

Comment: This is what I wanted to achieve, but why does it take so long to run? In the fiddle you probably won't notice it much, but if your site is a bit heavier, it will take quite a while to take effect.

Comment: Not sure why? There's nothing in that code that should make it slow as far as I can tell, and it starts right away here, so I can't really test it either !

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter that much, but if there's a solution to it, I'd like to know, thanks.